# if statement: check which condition qualifies

Tags: ruby, variables, if-statement

If I have an if statement

```
x = 2
y = 1
if x == nil || y == nil || z == nil
  raise "RuntimeError: Argument is nil"
end
```

would it be possible to do something like

```
raise "RuntimeError: ${Argument} is nil"
```

where the argument is the variable that is `nil`? Or, do I have to separate the conditions for that to work?

```
if x == nil 
  raise "RuntimeError: x is nil"
end

if y == nil 
  raise "RuntimeError: y is nil"
end

if z == nil 
  raise "RuntimeError: z is nil"
end
```

Is it possible to find which condition for an if statement passes so that the code inside that block is executed? In this case, it would be `z == nil`.

Comment: (1) Even before your error message is raised, your code will return an undefined error for `z`. (2) A constant `Argument` cannot change its value between `nil` and numbers throughout the code. (3) What do you mean by "the argument is the variable that is nil"? which argument are you mentioning?

Comment: By `raise "RuntimeError: z is nil"` you most likely wants to `raise RuntimeError, "z is nil"`

Comment: @fotanus or just `raise "z is nil"`, it defaults to `RuntimeError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While something like this "works":

```
%w(x y z).each { |var| raise "#{var} is nil" if eval(var).nil? }
```

I'd write one-liners:

```
raise "x is nil" if x.nil?
raise "y is nil" if y.nil?
raise "z is nil" if z.nil?
```

It's much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do it with a Hash:

```
{x: x, y: y, z: z}.each do |k, v|
  raise "RuntimeError: #{k} is nil" unless v
end
```

Comment: I assumed ${} was just a typo for `#{}`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you could avoid caring which is `nil`, you could write

```
raise "RuntimeError: an element in this range is nil" if [x, y, z].include? nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This too would work:

> ```
>  w = 1
>  x = nil
>  y = 4
>  z = nil
>
>  a = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'].find {|e| !eval(e)}
>  raise RuntimeError, ": #{a} is nil" if a
> ```

-> RuntimeError: : x is nil

...but I think you're better off with a simple if/then or case statement.